# Prove the following trignometric inequality for all real $x$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove the following trignometric inequality for all $x \in \Bbb R$
$$x^2 \sin(x) + x \cos(x) + x^2 + {\frac 12} >0$$

take $x$  in the form of radians.
This particular question is the seventh question of the  1995 Indian RMO.

Comment: Tough one. At $x\approx4.49355$ the expression is $\approx0.0060425$ and there are other points further along which are even closer to zero.

Comment: let's see if we can find out the minimum value of the expression

Comment: I'm pretty sure the minimum approach zero as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: I'am currently plotting the graph at a calculator. let's see if that could help.

Comment: [Graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+sin(x)+%2Bx+cos(x)+%2Bx%5E2+%2B+1%2F2+for+-5Pi%3Cx%3C5pi). It looks like that the more you zoom out.

Comment: I found some possible solutions [here](http://madanpur.in/rmo/rmo.htm). They leave out some of the steps which I can't seem to fill in.

Comment: Got it. The method II is mentioned in the answers. I could not understand the Method I,though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$. Now substitute it in the original expression. We have $$ x^{2}\sin x + x\cos x + x^{2} + \frac{1}{2}$$ $$= (1+\sin x)x^{2} + x\cos x+\frac{1}{2}$$ $$=(1 + \frac{2t}{1+t^{2}})x^{2} + x(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}) + \frac{1}{2}$$ $$= \frac{(1+t)^{2}}{1+t^{2}}[x^{2} - x\frac{1-t^{2}}{(1+t)^{2}} + \frac{(1-t^{2})^{2}}{4(1+t)^{4}} + \frac{1+t^{2}}{4}]$$ $$= \frac{(1+t)^{2}}{1+t^{2}}[x-\frac{1-t^{2}}{2(1+t)^{2}}]^{2} + \frac{(1+t)^{2}}{4} > 0. $$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of the "quadratic" equation is $$\cos^2x-2(\sin x+1)=-(\sin x+1)^2$$ and is non-positive.

When $\sin x=-1$, the inequation reduces to

$$-x^2+x^2+1/2>0,$$ which is true.

When $\sin x\ne-1$, there cannot be real roots, and the function is positive everywhere.

---

Very interestingly, a plot of the function will lead you to believe in an infinity of zero values of the LHS, thus invalidating the claim. Anyway, all these are false roots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: inequation? Portmanteau of inequality and equation?

Comment: @Squirtle: yep, a Frenglish word.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as $$f(x)=(1+\sin x)x^2+(\cos x) x+\frac 12$$

Multiply through by $4(1+\sin x)\ge 0$ to complete the square with $$4(1+\sin x)f(x)=$$

$$\left(2(1+\sin x)x+\cos x\right)^2-\cos^2x+2(1+\sin x)=(2(1+\sin x)x+\cos x)^2+(1+\sin x)^2\ge 0$$

As the sum of two squares (using $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$). Now any case of equality must have $1+\sin x=0$ and in this case $f(x)=\frac 12\gt 0$. So there is no case of equality for $f(x)$ and we have $f(x)\gt 0$.

Comment: Great answer. This was, by far, the simplest and the most logical solution I've seen to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more efficient ways but this is what I have:

If it is positive (i.e. nonnegative) then certainly when we multiply it by a positive function it will stay positive... to this end, multiply it by $\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$ this gives 
$$x^2\sin^3\cos^2(x)+x\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)+x^2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$

Now this is positive provided that $x^2\cos^2(x)(\sin^2(x)-\sin^3(x))$ is positive and similarly if $\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) - x\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)$ is positive.  I'll show that the first term is positive.  This first term is positive only if $g(x)=\sin^2(x)-\sin^3(x)$ is positive.
Upon taking the derivative we get that this function has roots precisely when $x=n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. If we compute the second derivative we get
$$g''(x) = 3\sin^3(x)-2\sin^2(x)+2\cos^2(x)-6\sin(x)\cos^2(x)$$
and at $x=n\pi$ we have that $g''(x)=2>0$, therefore the function is always positive and likewise we can check the other term $\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) - x\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)$ is positive.